# Bootstrap 4 - H3 inside Dropdown link

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

I have a doubt relating to the dropdown in a navbar. For the normal nav-link (no dropdown) I put the menu text inside an H3, but when I tried to do the same for the dropdown-link, the arrow is not next to the title but under it. I decided to replace the h3 with a span and give the same CSS as an h3, this time the arrow was on the right place, but all the other styles were not taken into account.

The third example is the one more close to what I want, but the font-size is not quite the same.

## Original code without dropdown

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#logo {
  max-height: 2.5rem;
}

.nav_container {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-top: .25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Original</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.0-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.0-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- FontAwesome5 Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <!-- Fin liens CSS et Script -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="index.php">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Home</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link1</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link2</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link3</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link4</h3>
          </a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## My tries

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#logo {
  max-height: 2.5rem;
}

.nav_container {
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

#navbardrop {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#navbardrop2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#navbardrop3 { 
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-top: .25rem;
}

#admin_menu {
  font-weight: 700!important;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-top: .25rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-top: .25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.0-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap 4.0-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- FontAwesome5 Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <!-- Fin liens CSS et Script -->
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Try 1</h2>
  <div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="index.php">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Home</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link 1</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link2</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link3</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link4</h3>
          </a>
        </li>

        <!-- Admin  -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <h3 id="admin_menu">Admin</h3>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <h4>Admin1</h4>
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <h4>Admin2</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <h2>Try 2</h2>

  <div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="index.php">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Home</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link 1</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link2</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link3</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link4</h3>
          </a>
        </li>

        <!-- Admin  -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop2" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="admin_menu">Admin</span></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <h4>Admin1</h4>
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <h4>Admin2</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <h2>Try 3</h2>

  <div class="nav_container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/440u9.png"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="index.php">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Home</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link 1</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link2</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link3</h3>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold">Link4</h3>
          </a>
        </li>

        <!-- Admin  -->
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" id="navbardrop3" data-toggle="dropdown">Admin</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <h4>Admin1</h4>
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
              <h4>Admin2</h4>
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

give `position:relative` to h3 and `position:absolute` to :after and adjust it accordingly. thanks

Comment: To which case (1, 2 or 3)?

Comment: add that to the try  1

Comment: It didn't work but thanks anyway; I used a workaround to solve my problem. I just put display none to ".dropdown-toggle::after" and then added a span inside the h3 with FontAwesome class.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

### CSS

```
#navbardrop{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

#admin_menu {
  font-weight: 700!important;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-top: .25rem; 
}

h3{
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after{
    display: none;
}

h4{
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="nav_container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="homepage"><img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="index.php"><h3 class="font-weight-bold">Accueil</h3></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="add_mat.php"><h3 class="font-weight-bold">Ajout Matériel</h3></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="add_cat.php"><h3 class="font-weight-bold">Ajout Catégorie</h3></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="add_type.php"><h3 class="font-weight-bold">Ajout Type</h3></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="add_model.php"><h3 class="font-weight-bold">Ajout Modèle</h3></a>
                    </li>

                    <!-- Admin  -->
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <h3 id="admin_menu">Admin <span class="fas fa-angle-down"></span></h3>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="../update_data.php"><h4>Update Data</h4></a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="../bd_tables.php"><h4>Tableaux BD</h4></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

### Result

[image]